# How to work with dd command?

Tags: usb, scripts

If I have executed below commands,

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/cdrom/usbfile.bin bs=1024 count=1048576
```

Getting error as

```
dd: opening `/mnt/cdrom/usbfile.bin': No such file or directory.
```

How to create a `usbfile.bin` file? I thought after executing above mentioned command, it will create `usbfile.bin` file. But I'm getting error.

Comment: There exists the directory `/mnt/cdrom`?

Comment: yes.I have created that directories.

Comment: Have you double checked its existence after the creation command?

Comment: Yeah.It is there.But usbfile.bin is not creating

Answer (score 1):

To simply create the file, use command `touch /path/to/file`. But you have to be sure that this path exists and you have write permissions into that directory.

Now, you choose `/mnt/cdrom` as path to file. This is obsolete path to CD-ROM. Since it was created manually (probably with `sudo` prefix), it allows writing there only to the root user. Correct path is `/media/cdrom`. And even if it was mounted, you would have no write permissions into that directory, because it is a CD-***R**ead **O**nly **M**emory*. The only way you can write files directly onto CD filesystem is using DVD+R/DVD+RW disks.

So, the right command in your case would be such:

```
touch ~/usbfile.bin
dd if=/dev/zero of=~/usbfile.bin bs=1024 count=1048576
```

Then burn this file on DVD. I still have no idea why do you need this wasting of DVD, but if you want to do this, it is the right way.